# What is this mini pop-up box and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: gui-emacs, ubuntu

I don't know what combination of keys I pressed to bring up this mini-box, but it's annoying me.

What is it and how do I get rid of it?

EDIT:

It pops up when I press `C-S-u`
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It's an Ubuntu method of [entering Unicode characters by typing their code points](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html). I'm not sure how to disable it.

Comment: There's always something to get in the way...Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is an answer from a few years ago, but you could look at this answer from askubuntu.com. I'm not at an Ubuntu machine, so I can't try it now. Look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/367646/is-it-possible-to-unbind-or-change-the-unicode-input-global-shortcut